# Count number of Strings that can be converted to Int in a List

Tags: scala

For example, my input is:

```
scala> val myList = List("7842", "abf45", "abd", "56")
myList: List[String] = List(7842, abf45, abd, 56)
```

`7842` and `56` can be converted to `Int`; therefore, my expected output is `2`. We can assume that negative integers don't happen, so `-67` is not possible.

This is what I have so far:

```
scala> myList.map(x => Try(x.toInt).getOrElse(-1)).count(_ > -1)
res15: Int = 2
```

This should work correctly, but I feel like I am missing a more elegant and readable solution, because all I have to do is count number of successes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would caution against using exception handling (like `Try`) in control flow -- it's very slow.

Here's a solution that uses idiomatic Scala collection operations, performs well, and will not count negative numbers:

```
scala> val myList = List("7842", "abf45", "abd", "56")
myList: List[String] = List(7842, abf45, abd, 56)

scala> myList.count(_.forall(_.isDigit)) 
res8: Int = 2
```

EDIT: @immibis pointed out that this won't detect strings of numbers that exceed `Integer.MaxValue`.  If this is a concern, I would recommend one of the following approaches:

```
import scala.util.Try
myList.count(x => Try(x.toInt).filter(_ >= 0).isSuccess)
```

or, if you want to keep the performance of my first answer while still handling this edge case:

```
import scala.util.Try
myList.count(x => x.forall(_.isDigit) && Try(x.toInt).filter(_ >= 0).isSuccess)
```

Comment: What about 1000000000000000000000000000000? What's the maximum value for an Int in Scala?

Comment: That's a very good point.  Scala Int is a 32-bit signed integer, so the maximum value is 2^31 - 1 (2147483647).  I'll think about this and update my answer.

Comment: `I would caution against using exception handling (like Try) in control flow -- it's very slow.` Very slow even for an input `List[String]` consisting of a few elements?

Comment: 100 microseconds vs 1 microsecond doesn't matter much if you're doing it once, that's true.  But evaluating this code on every line of a text file, for example, can cause that difference to become very important.

Answer (score 8):

This is a bit shorter:

```
myList.count(x => Try(x.toInt).isSuccess)
```

Note that this solution will handle any string that can be converted to integer via `.toInt`, including negative numbers.

Comment: This doesn't check the positive condition.  It's also very inefficient to use exception handling as control flow.

Comment: @TimP I agree, yours is more efficient for this case and works specially well because there are no negative numbers (it's possible to include negatives but would be a bit more verbose). My solution simply handles any string that can be converted to integer via `.toInt`.

Answer (score 4):

You may consider `string.matches` method with regex as well, to match only positive integers:

```
val myList = List("7842", "abf45", "abd", "-56")
// myList: List[String] = List(7842, abf45, abd, -56)

myList.count(_.matches("\\d+"))
// res18: Int = 1
```

If negative integers need to be counted (and take into account possible +/- signs):

```
myList.count(_.matches("[+-]?\\d+"))
// res17: Int = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Scala 2.13` and the introduction of [`String::toIntOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/StringOps.html#toIntOption:Option[Int]), we can count items (`"34"`/`"2s3"`) for which applying `toIntOption` (`Some(34)`/`None`) is defined (`true/false`):

```
List("34", "abf45", "2s3", "56").count(_.toIntOption.isDefined) // 2
```